# Multiple colors per axis based on value

Tags: dygraphs

I'm using awesome dygraphs library to draw data. Values range from 0 to 100. Is it possible to have 1 color for data between 0-50, other color for 51-80 and another color for 81-100.

The point is to better demonstrate data. 0-50 is normal (green), 51-80 is warning (yellow) and 81-100 is alarm (red).

I know dygraphs has highlighted regions (http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/highlighted-region) but this is not it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [drawPointCallback](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/02/new-feature-custom-points.html) feature to do this.

```js
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  drawPointCallback: function(g, seriesName, canvasContext, cx, cy, seriesColor, pointSize, row) {
    var col = g.indexFromSetName(seriesName);
    var val = g.getValue(row, col);
    var color = '';
    if (val >= 0 && val <= 50) {
      color = 'green';
    } else if (val > 50 && val <= 80) {
      color = 'yellow';
    } else if (val > 80) {
      color = 'red';
    }
    if (color) {
      canvasContext.beginPath();
      canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
      canvasContext.strokeStyle = seriesColor;
      canvasContext.arc(cx, cy, pointSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      canvasContext.fill();
      canvasContext.stroke();
    }
  }, 
  drawPoints: true,
  pointSize: 5,
  highlightCircleSize: 8
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/3335/).