# Highlight coordinates dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

i am generating a graph using digraph combined library. Is there any way to highlight coordinate points in graph, like some colourful dots or anything that highlight coordinate points.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. See the [custom points option](http://blog.dygraphs.com/2012/02/new-feature-custom-points.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916903/multiple-colors-per-axis-based-on-value/24370423#24370423).